# How can I store 1M lists with fast retrieval effectively?

Tags: database, nosql, html-lists, storage

The list format will be:

1. list item one (I) - details
2. list item two (I)
3. list item three (I) - details
4. list item four (o)
5. list item five (o)
6. list item six (I) - details

Note that:

- order is important; hence the numbering
- each item can either be (I) imperative or (o) optional
- lists must be easily editable in pretty much every way
- some list items include a description field (- details)
- the list items and descriptions must be search able
- each list might be requested and edited by more than one outside instance at a time

***Question: What sort of database/storage model should I use?***

Some brainstorming from my part: PostgresSQL table + Directory storage

- each list will be listed as a name/link in the table
- the list themselves will be stored as individual files in HTML/XML markup
- searching of list body would be executed by grep (?)

Comment: A million lists isn't cool. You know what's cool? A billion lists.

Comment: But seriously though, a million isn't a lot for a db. Postgresql is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Put the whole thing into the database - no files, no XML, no grep.

There is nothing in your question that indicates why you would need hybrid storage (like size, exotic features or legacy interfacing).  Regardless of which database you use (almost - I can see the [nosql](/questions/tagged/nosql) tag but that is not very specific), it will cope well.

Forget about XML, unless you have an external need for it.  XML is no match for a database if all it contains is a long list of simple values, of name-value pairs, or something equally database friendly.

Forget about grep if you use *either* of database or XML.  Use that technology's respective search primitives instead.